# Breaking a recursive and iterative method

Tags: java, recursion, methods, iteration

Can anyone help me breaking this method and return the actual value of "stop" once "stop" is true? Notice that "stop" starting with false.

```
private boolean handleRoot(ITreeNode node, String rmiDefUuidInit, int columnIndex, String chartName, boolean stop) {
for (ITreeNode childNode : node.getChilds()){
    if (!stop && !childNode.isSelected())
        stop = true;
    handleRoot(childNode, rmiDefUuidInit, columnIndex, chartName, stop);
}
return !stop;}
```

It seems like, my post isn't clear enough. First I put this example together so it can be simple and easy to understand. My code is much complex than that.

Here is the problem: I have a TreeViewer in which I want to select the parent node if all his children and the children's children are all selected. For performance reason I figured, I can stop as soon as I cross a none selected child-node and break the routine. This is basically my problem since the iteration continues with the value of "stop = false" as soon as my actual iteration ends.

Comment: You could immediately `return true` instead of `stop = true`.

Comment: This code cannot compile. `childNode` is not a boolean.

Comment: not really since I want the function to also return false when there's no node selected. I'll edited it for better understand.

Comment: `if (!stop && childNode != null) {` in java (instead of C/C++)

Comment: I guess the goal is to check the RootNode if all the chil-Nodes in his subtree are checked or break the iteration and the recursiv-call once a child is met which isn't selected yet and returning FALSE when this is the case

Comment: I understand your condition the following way: If we do not already want to stop, and the childNode is not selected, we want to stop. However, after reaching this condition you call the function recursively. What about your stop intention?

Comment: If stop is true which means there's a child "not selected" stop = true and the function should return !stop which means false and the parent would not be checked. If stop stays false this means all children are selected and it will return true

Comment: If you want to not recurse down into children if siblings aren't selected, consider a breadth first algorithm rather than a depth first.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand from your description you probably wanted to do this:

```
private boolean handleRoot(ITreeNode node, String rmiDefUuidInit, int columnIndex, String chartName) {
    for (ITreeNode childNode: node.getChilds()) {
        if (!childNode.isSelected()) return true;
        if (handleRoot(childNode, rmiDefUuidInit, columnIndex, chartName)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code will return `true` if the tree contains any non-selected `TreeNode`, and false otherwise. When it finds a non-selected `TreeNode` it will skip checking other nodes and step out of recursion.